# Collecting GStreamer logs in Python ends with Segmentation fault

Tags: python, logging, gstreamer, glib, python-gstreamer

I try to process logs from Gstreamer using Python.

I created file `test_logging.py`

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import GLib, Gst


def _process_message(
    category: Gst.DebugCategory,
    level: Gst.DebugLevel,
    filename: str,
    function: str,
    line: int,
    object,
    message: Gst.DebugMessage,
    user_data,
):
    msg_str = message.get()
    msg_str = f"{filename} {msg_str}"

    print(msg_str)


Gst.init(None)
Gst.debug_remove_log_function()
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
    "uridecodebin name=decoder uri=file:///opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream/samples/streams/sample_720p.mp4 ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink"
)

Gst.debug_add_log_function(_process_message, user_data=pipeline)
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
try:
    loop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    pass
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
loop.quit()
```

I attached handler using [Gst.debug_add_log_function](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstinfo.html?gi-language=python#gst_debug_add_log_function).

And everything seems to work fine in regular scenarios. `python3 test_logging.py` works fine, but I miss most of my logs, so when I bump log level with flag `GST_DEBUG=3` I get Segfault:

```
$ GST_DEBUG=3 python3 ./test_log.py 
xvcontext.c MIT-SHM extension check failed at XShmAttach. Not using shared memory.
gstbasesrc.c pad not activated yet
gstbasesrc.c pad not activated yet
qtdemux_types.c unknown QuickTime node type sgpd
qtdemux_types.c unknown QuickTime node type sbgp
....More irrelevant logs
gstv4l2object.c Unable to try format: Unknown error -1
gstv4l2object.c Could not probe maximum capture size for pixelformat H264
gstv4l2object.c Unable to try format: Unknown error -1
gstv4l2object.c Could not probe minimum capture size for pixelformat NM12
gstv4l2object.c Unable to try format: Unknown error -1
gstv4l2object.c Could not probe maximum capture size for pixelformat NM12
sys:1: Warning: g_object_is_floating: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
sys:1: Warning: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Do you know how to fix this problem?

In the docs I found:

> Be sure to use [G_GNUC_NO_INSTRUMENT (not introspectable)](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#G-GNUC-NO-INSTRUMENT:CAPS) on that function, it is needed.

But I don't know how to use it in Python.

Comment: Ran into the same issue (encountered the *SegFault* in other plugins as well). Didn't get to the bottom of it, but using *xvimagesink* (that *autovideosink*bin  automatically instantiates) directly, did the trick for me.

Comment: @CristiFati I resteted it with Gstreamer 1.20 (instead of 1.16) and everything worked. It seems to be a bug. I reported it here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/3253

Comment: Good news! Unfortunately for me, I don't have the privilege of upgrading the version.

Comment: Opened https://stackoverflow.com/q/77932526/4788546, will mark this as a duplicate.